# Advice on Story Text-Based Game

Tags: unity, text-based

I am currently in preparation on making a game. This game will be looks like Lifeline by 3 Minute Games, which is a story text-based game.

My game will have the same concept with it. Where there will be a scrollable history of conversation between player and characters in game. However, my game will has more than one conversation history. He will be able to interact with more than one character. Therefore, when the game start, it will show list of interactable characters in game, and player can choose who he will interact with when any available.

I am planning to make it with Unity. But I don't know is it possible to create some scrollable history of text, each with different content, like chat history, in Unity.

So I wanna ask your opinion, is it good to just continue with using Unity, or should I change the game engine I use? If I should change, what is the best game engine to cope with this kind of game?

Thank in advance :)

Comment: We don't answer "which technology to use" questions here. Really, just about any game engine or framework will be up to the task of showing you multiple scrolling histories of text. You should try implementing first, and ask questions here if you run into trouble - then you can describe the specific problem you're having and what you've tried so far to overcome it.

Comment: Well, I just wanna ask is it possible to make such game in Unity or not. Cause I not an expert in Unity myself.

Comment: Anyway, where should I ask this kind of question, then?

Comment: There might be no place on the net where you will get an objective non-biased answer to this. However, I can tell you Unity "*probably* is not the best option for this style of game you want. You might be better of doing something from scratch at whatever programming language you know...

Comment: rlam12 is on point. And asking for opinions is never a good thing on the internet. Any programing language can display text in a window, without the addition of a super advanced 3d game engine whose features you don't plan to use. Bazooka - Fly.

Answer (score 2):

Unity can be used for your simple text based game using the UI features. It makes deploying to multiple platforms relatively easy. Although if you have no prior experience with Unity, you might want to consider something easier to use which would not overwhelm you with features.